# Testfor Spamming

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm on version 1.12.2. When I do `testfor @p[r=2]`, it spams the console with this.
When it spams the console like this, I cannot use it:

[image]

Comment: That is not a valid command in current Minecraft versions and doesn't produce that error message. `/testfor` was removed almost 2 years ago. Which version of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm playing on 1.12.2.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do against that, except:

- updating to 1.15.2, where `/execute` does not print anything when there is no matching entity (but be aware of an [item deletion bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-147729), a [chunk loading bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-147818) and the absence of customised worlds)
- turning off all command feedback, even successes and other errors: `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false`

Comment: Thank you! I recently downgraded from 1.15.2 to 1.12.2 due to command problems. I ran that command and still spamming. Thanks though! If you have any other ideas please tell me!

Comment: Because of commands? Why? Those are WAY better in 1.13+! They're pretty much the only reason why I endured 1.13's and 1.14's horrible performance at all. Also, if this did not answer your question, why did you mark it as accepted?

Comment: As you mentioned before, "There's not much you can do against that". So I marked it as a answer, because apparantly there is no other way. And for the 1.15.2, many commands that wee need are based on 1.12.2 so we decided to switch.

Comment: No, 1.12.2 has no features that 1.15.2 doesn't have, except for customised worlds. You can do absolutely everything in 1.15.2 that you can do in 1.12.2.

Comment: Ok! I just prefer 1.12.2 but thanks for the idea!